# Como setar `href` em um link no KnockoutJS?

Tags: javascript, html, link, knockoutjs

Estou começando com KnockoutJS e gostaria de saber se tem como anexar um link recebido por AJAX/JSON em uma tag `<a href="meu link aqui">Meu link</a>`.

### HTML:

```html
<div data-bind="text: url"></div>

<hr/>

<a data-bind="href: url">Google</a>
```

### Javascript:

```javascript
function App() {
  this.url = "http://www.google.com.br/";
}

ko.applyBindings( new App() );
```

No JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3V53L/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta utilizar o binding `attr`

```
<a data-bind="attr: { href: url }">
    Report
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        url: ko.observable("http://www.google.com.br/"),
    };
</script>
```

fonte: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: Bem simples. Preciso ler a documentação. =)